# Signals and Division by Zero

Tags: c++, linux, signals, posix, divide-by-zero

I'm getting an unwanted result of division by zero in my code (the code is written in C++):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fenv.h>

void div0(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *ucontext)
{
    if(signo == SIGFPE && info->si_code == FPE_FLTDIV)
    {
        std::cout << "You can't divide numbers by 0, idiot!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main()
{
    feenableexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);

    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_NODEFER;
    act.sa_sigaction = div0;

    int retn = sigaction(SIGFPE, &act, NULL);
    if(retn == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        return -1;
    }

    int n1, n2;

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> n1;

    std::cout << "Enter another number to divide by: ";
    std::cin >> n2;

    double div = n1 / 1.0 / n2;
    std::cout << n1 << " / " << n2 << " = " << div << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I assign the value `0` in the variable `n2`, the result is, for example: `5 / 0 = inf`. But I want to get: `You can't divide numbers by zero, idiot!`. I used the `SIGFPE` signal with the `FPE_FLTDIV` signal code, and I tried to change the `double` to `float`, but it still didn't work. I searched on the Internet and I didn't find any solution. Did I miss something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: First, how are you compiling your program?  And you can't safely use `cout` in a signal handler.  Per [footnote 188 of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note188): "Thus, a signal handler cannot, in general, call standard library functions."  POSIX allows you to call async-signal-safe functions, but `cout` is not one of them.  [Linux provides a list](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) of Linux-specific async-signal-safe functions.  If it's not on that list, you can't safely use it in a signal handler - which means no C++ streams...

Comment: @AndrewHenle so which IO function is signal-safe? I compile the program in g++.

Comment: `write()`.  That's about it.  No C++ stream, not even `fprintf()` or `fwrite()`.  You can get away with using even `cout` in a small program like this (most of the time...), but when things get more complex it gets dangerous.

Comment: I don't know whether that's relevant here, but generally, floating point errors don't throw any signals - the result is just NaN. You might need to change some floating point settings as well.

Comment: @PMF  With GCC, that can depend on the compilation options.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: Why are you doing it like that? Can you not just check the value beforehand?

Comment: `std::cout` and `std::cin` aren't signal-safe, but it doesn't interferes. I changed the `div` to `int` and I got the wanted output.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I used all of those flags, but it still gave me the same output.

Comment: I enabled floating-point-exceptions via `feenableexcept` and I got the wanted output. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Matan> note that division by zero is undefined behavior, so you cannot get a consistent result. If the compiler can optimize your code by removing the division entirely, it is allowed to do so (and thus you won't get a signal). It might not, but it can - and it might not today, but maybe a future version will.

Comment: @spectras It's unlikely the compiler will eliminate the division here, since the arguments are coming from the command line.

Comment: @PMF> unlikely does not mean impossible. And the point is also that whatever specific behavior you witness here and now cannot be extrapolated to any other piece of code, or even to the same piece of code with another compiler. The compiler is allowed to assume that n2 cannot and will not ever be 0, and generate binary accordingly. What this means depends on many details.

Comment: I edited the code to the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not trying simple `if (n2 == 0) std::cout << "You can't divide numbers by zero, i***t!"`

Another approach would be `if isnan(div) std::cout << "You already divided by zero, i***t!"`

The devision 0/0 is silent in `double` and `float`. You will receive a `NaN` instead of any exception. This will allow you to better handle the error.

**Added to address the comment**

If you want to generate the signal, you need to use all of the variables as `integer` and avoid optimizations from the compiler. There is very good example in the book "The linux programming interface" which [you can find here](https://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/signals/demo_SIGFPE.c.html)

Comment: I'm learning signals in Linux, so I have to do that using signals.

Comment: @Matan I updated the answer with a link to an example that generates the SIGFPE